# What is the standard format for the MPL-2.0 license modification notice?

Tags: copyright, license-notice, mpl

I would like to use a modified version of open-source code licensed under MPL 2.0 in my own open-source code, also licensed under MPL 2.0. But I'm unsure about the specific standard format for specifying the copyright notice.

How should I specify copyright notice in this case? To be more precise:

1. What is the exact format for writing the previous author and myself?
2. Should I insert the entire source code of the version I'm trying to modify as a comment in my own code? And if yes, is there a more straightforward but still legal way to do this?
3. Does it matter if the copyright notice is at the beginning of a file or in the end?
4. Should I mention the entire license text or can I just provide a link to a license? And what is the exact text for saying this?
5. Are the rules different if my code is not licensed under MPL 2.0?
6. How do I find out these rules in general for any combination of two licenses: the original code and my own code?

Comment: The ideal format is the format which the software uses - and to amend yours in the same way.